# PhantomJS rendering error

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

When I open a local HTML file with phantomJS and save it as a PNG, it renders the `input[type="number"]` element incorrectly:

[image]

The elements use bootstrap form CSS; the Age input normally goes all the way to the right, though there is a browser added ticket to increment/decrement the input. Is there any way to get phantomJS to render it the same way it appears in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: Nope, PhantomJS renders it the way the version of webkit it is built with tells it to. You certainly can't make it look like Chrome (which uses Blink) or Firefox (Gecko). See "which webkit version is used by PhantomJS" here: http://phantomjs.org/faq.html

Comment: Ah. I thought Chrome used webkit since it has CSS properties prefixed with it.

Comment: Chrome used to use webkit, it now uses a(n open source) google backed rendering engine called blink. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(layout_engine)